# How can you set cookieless subdomain with Quantcast

Tags: cookie, quantcast

I have correctly setup Google Analtycis so GA is not setting cookies for my subdomain. I mean for my static subdomain. But Quantcast is setting. What i wonder is can i prevent Quantcast to set cookie to my static subdomain which is static.example.com?

Comment: It may help my answer if you can conclude how you think the Quantcast cookie is being saved on the static sub domain.

Answer (score 1):

If you only execute JS on the www. domain then it is not possible that cookies will be saved on static, unless something fundamentally wrong with your setup and your static is not cookieless.

`__qca P0-1877480803-1366306458351 .monstermmorpg.com   32 B /`

Just because it doesn't have `www.` doesn't mean its cookieing on the static... Maybe you mean something else?

Comment: i dont understand your answer. yes static.monstermmorpg.com is cookiless. i did setup correctly with google analytics and GA not anymore setting any cookie on static.monstermmorpg.com